# Поставленный на паузу AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Имеется много *AsyncTask*, которые запускаются с помощью метода `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params)`. То есть, как я понимаю, все эти таски ставятся в очередь и последовательно выполняются один за другим.

Допустим, я захотел приостановить их выполнение, и ставлю их на паузу (приостановка и продолжение тасков у меня реализовано примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474584/pause-and-resume-asynctasks-android/18687278#18687278)).

После этого я решаю отменить все задачи. Теперь я хочу начать эти задачи заново.

И вот тут проблема: таски не запускаются.

Я предполагаю, что это происходит потому, что предыдущие таски, которые я отменил, все еще висят в памяти и при этом имеют статус паузы. Поэтому система пытается их завершить, но не может (так как они приостановлены). А так как выполнение тасков происходит последовательно, то и новые не стартуют.

Я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы можно было эти приостановленные (и к тому же отмененные) таски как-то убить, чтобы дать понять системе что пора бы вополнять новые таски.

Я нашел костыльный способ, как этого достигнуть: при отмене таска я сначала проверяю, не приостановлен ли он, и если да, то возобновляю его выполнение и тут же отменяю его. Но это довольно грязный прием.

Может быть, есть какой то способ получше и понадежнее убить эти приостановленные таски?

Answer (score 1):

Прервать таску можно вызвав у нее `cancel(true)`:

```
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {...};
    // ...
    task.cancel(true);
```

При этом если она спит вызовется `InterruptedException`.

Comment: так я и делаю. Но не помогает

Comment: @JuniorThree должно работать, есть подозрение что вы что-то делаете не так. Можете собрать минимальный пример где воспроизводится эта проблема?